# How many NIC's in relation to processor cores?

Tags: networking, nic

I have server with four cores procesor (non HT) and two NIC's onboard.

Is it reasonable to add four additional NIC's (ie. Intel PRO/1000PT) or only two new NIC's will be enough (ie. Intel PCI-E D33025)? In other words – are there any relation between number of main processor cores and number of NIC's? What about processors with HT?

All card will work together using bonding under Linux. Please skip other issues like I/O subsystem performance.

EDIT:

Possible scenario 1: Backup server using backuppc and about 20 clients. A lot of traffic with small packets (server checks if file was modified on client, makes/checs md5 checksum against files).

Possible scenario 2: File server, 20 clients. Almost only small transfers from/to Widows clients. Average per day: RX: 20 GiB, TX: 150 GiB.

Comment: The number of NICs you can use has nothing to do with the number of CPU cores

Comment: On top, a NIC is not a NIC / some use more CPU than others. And you say so absolutely niothing about how many you NEED. If the server does not do heavy network IO you never ever need more than one.

Comment: That's what I'm not sure about. For every request from clients I need at least one threat on main processor. Question could be expanded to: Did one core could handle requests from more then one NIC. Is modern cores fast enough so they can prepare data faster than gigabit NIC's can transfer data?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 1):

A single core on a modern processor can handle a full 10 gigabit NIC, if you have the right NIC and the right type of traffic. Lower quality NICs will require more processor time. Lots of short connections will also require more processor time than fewer, sustained connections. Then you have to add in whatever processor time your application/service needs to service the clients.

The only way to know what you need is to test and benchmark your environment. No one here can give you the right answers.

Comment: Thanks, I will have shortly some spare parts (NIC's) to do some tests with first scenario.